# nontrivial solvable group contains a nontrivial characteristic abelian subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading about algebra and I have these questions to prove along with my attempts, any help is highly appreciated:

(i) Show that a nontrivial solvable group contains a nontrivial characteristic abelian subgroup.

(ii) Show that a nontrivial solvable group has a nontrivial abelian factor subgroup.

(iii) Show that a nonsolvable group contains a nontrivial characteristic subgroup $N$ such that $ N'= N $

(iv) Let $G$ be a solvable group, and let $ 1 \neq H \triangleleft G $. Show that there is an $A$ such that $1 \neq A \triangleleft G $ and $A \leq  H $ and $A$ is abelian.

My attempt:

If a group is solvable, then there must be a $G^{(s)} = 1$ for some integer $s \geq 0$. Then there must be a subnormal series of $G$ with abelian factors, which solves the second question( right ?).

If $G$ is not solvable, its derived series cannot reach $1$.

Comment: Note that the derived series is not just a subnormal series, but a normal series and even a characteristic series. This should help.

Comment: For i) you can also take the socle, i.e. the product of all minimal normal subgroups.

Comment: @the_fox Not all groups have minimal normal subgroups - $({\mathbb Z},+)$ for example.

Comment: @DerekHolt There was a "finite groups" tag, which made me think the question was about finite groups exclusively.

Comment: (iii) is false for suitable infinite groups. (i),(ii),(iv) are true without finiteness assumption.